# why row is not render in angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to send data from one component to another using `input` attr.
but I am getting this error

```
VM575 zone.js@0.6.17?main=browser:484 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 't' since it isn't a known property of 'row-item'.
1. If 'row-item' is an Angular component and it has 't' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'row-item' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("          <ul>
                 <li *ngFor="let tt of todoService.todos">
                <row-item [ERROR ->][t]='tt'></row-item>
                  </li>
```

I added this in my demo

```
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector:'row-item',
  template :`<div>
 <span>{{t}}</span>
</div>`
})
export class TodoRow{
  @Input t;
}
```

used like this

```
@Component({
    selector: 'todo-list',
    template: `<div>
                <ul>
                 <li *ngFor="let tt of todoService.todos">
                <row-item [t]='tt'></row-item>
                  </li>
                    </ul>
                   </div>`
})
```

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/WXgdKF2gx9Kpj7eqmDJv?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration should be something like this:

```
@Input() t;
```

Comment: or `@Input('t') t;`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add () while defining you input for the component.

```
import {Input} from '@angular/core';

Input() t;
```

You should try providing base name while providing input for the component:

```
@Input('t') t;
```

Hope this helps.